# List a list of all member from a group using graph api

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

How to display all users from a groups using Microsoft Graph api.

I would like to return a list of all current member from a group, however there is multiple page to iterate through it, and this return a different object than what I would like.

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
var groupAndMembers = await Graph.Groups[groupId].Request().Expand("members").GetAsync();
var usersInGroup = groupAndMembers.Members.ToList();
```

However there is two item I failed using this code, it return only 20 members, when I know for a fact i should have about 4000 users, so i am not to sure what element should i Use to navigate through the next link.

And my second issues, its been converted into List is there not a direct way to convert them to a List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to list all members for a specific group you can create request directly for the specific group. The response type will be `IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage`.

You need to fetch all pages and store result for each page.

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
var groupMembers = await Graph.Groups[groupId].Members.Request().GetAsync();
// type of groupMembers.CurrentPage is IList<DirectoryObject> 
// User derives from DirectoryObject
// add result for the first page
users.AddRange(groupMembers.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());
// fetch next page
while(groupMembers.NextPageRequest!=null)
{
    groupMembers = await groupMembers.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    users.AddRange(groupMembers.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());
}
```